Trouble Loading CSS Files in Kivy App Using WebView
I'm currently developing a mobile app with Kivy where I load HTML templates into a WebView. While the HTML templates load correctly, I've encountered an issue with loading CSS files. Here’s how I've set it up:
Project Structure:
project_strucuture
In index.html, I'm referencing CSS files like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/other_styles.css">

import webview
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class WebViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        window = webview.create_window('My App', 'templates/index.html', width=800, height=600)
        return BoxLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WebViewApp().run()

Despite setting up the directory structure and referencing CSS files correctly in index.html, the app consistently logs 404 errors for each CSS file attempted to load. Here's a snapshot of the error in the console:
Thank you!
Certainly! Here's a response to the prompt:
I attempted to build a mobile app using Kivy where I load HTML templates into a WebView component. The HTML templates load successfully, but I encountered issues with loading CSS files. Here’s a breakdown:
What I tried:
Created a directory structure with static/assets/css for CSS files and templates for HTML files.
Referenced CSS files in index.html using <link> tags with relative paths like <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/main.css">.
Configured the Kivy app to create a WebView window pointing to index.html.

Expected outcome:
I expected the app to load main.css and other CSS files specified in index.html without errors, as they are located in the static/assets/css directory relative to the HTML files.
Actual result:
When running the app, I consistently received 404 errors for each CSS file attempt. The console output indicated that the app could not find the CSS files at the specified paths.
error in the console

Please make it less obvious that GPT generated this... You did not even took the time to read what you paste
